# Nginx image_filter

Tags: static, nginx, amazon-s3, webserver, image

I store static on S3 and use [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) as front-end. For fetch from S3 I use this construction:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @s3;
}

location @s3 {
    root /var/www/static.dev;
    proxy_pass https://bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com;
    proxy_store off; # for test purposes
    proxy_store_access all:rw;
    proxy_temp_path /dev/shm;
}
```

This work!
But I want to generate thumbs and use this location:

```
if ( $uri ~ ^/t/ ) {
    set $w 182;
    set $h 114;
}
if ( $uri ~ ^/m/ ) {
    set $w 640;
    set $h 1280;
}
if ( $uri ~ ^/l/ ) {
    set $w 1024;
    set $h 2048;
}

location ~ ^/(?:t|m|l)/(.*\.(?:jpg|gif|png))$ {
    rewrite ^/[t|m|l]+/(.*)$ /$1;
    image_filter crop $w $h;
}
```

But this not work, nginx return `415 Unsupported Media Type`.
What wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be like to use the location directive on the each part of url: t/m/l.

```
location ( ~ ^/t/ ) {
    set $w 182;
    set $h 114;
    root /;
    image_filter crop $w $h;
}
```